# Problem importing custom modules in python using VSCode

Tags: java, python, import

I'm trying to import custom modules I made with python using VSCode, but every time I try to import a module this error shows up

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

I'm actually developing a game with the server in java and the client in python because the game is supposed to communicate with sockets, but I don't know why python cannot import the custom modules to another .py file, this is how my project structure looks like

src

|-- main

```
 |-- java
       |-- cr 
           |-- ac 
               |-- tec 
                    | -- JavaServer 
                    | -- PythonClient 
                              |-- Connection 
                              | -- GameFeatures 
                              | -- GameGui
                                      |-- GameMain.py 
                                      |-- GUI.py 
                                      | -- Platform.py
                                      | -- settings.py 
                                      | -- sprites.py
```

this is how I've been trying to import my modules to the GameMain file, but still, it doesn't work

from src.main.java.cr.ac.tec.PythonClient.GameGui.sprites import *

Comment: The directory `src` is in would need to be in the `PYTHONPATH`, and each directory in the entire chain would need to have an `__init__.py` to indicate that it is a python subpackage. That being said, using `src` as your package name is not a good idea, as it's not very unique. You'd be better off adding one of the subdirectories to `PYTHONPATH` and naming that directory something unique, like the name of your game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Create a blank `__init__.py` under the folder **GameGui** to declare it as a Module;

2.Add the following code in [launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_initialize-configurations) to make python extension search modules under root project, then you can directly import the module:

```
    "env": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}",
    },
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
```

[image: final result]